# Wordpress: Custom WP_Query returning first page posts for all 'paged' parameter values

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a "load more posts" button for my Wordpress blog page using AJAX. The Javascript function that takes care of passing the **'paged'**, **'offset'** and **'posts_per_page'** parameters is doing so successfully (I've checked a hundred times!).

The **offset** and **posts_per_page** parameters work fine (I repeatedly changed their values to test this) but the **WP_Query** always returns the posts on the front page, even though the value of **$page** changes each time more posts are loaded.

Just incase the **$paged** value was getting messed up somewhere, I used static numbers for the **'paged'** parameter but it still only shows first page posts no matter what the value.

Everything executes fine and I receive no error message, with debugging enabled. The posts do load - just not the right ones.

Other info: my own theme, no plugins running right now.

The code below is from a function in my **functions.php** file.

```
    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby'    =>  'date',
        'order'      =>  'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'paged'    => $page,
        'offset'  => $offset, //I've tried simply putting 3, 5 etc
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($loop -> have_posts()) : 
        while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

I've only entered what I believe to be relevant code, in order to make it easier to read. Let me know if you'd like me to add something. And thank you!

**EDIT:** Using the query() function directly makes it work but I really don't want to mess with the main query object...and this just means that everything else in my code is fine. WP_Query is just being weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't used `offset` and `paged` together - you would only use one or the other. Using them together breaks pagination. If you want the posts that would appear on page 2 (assuming you have 10 to a page), use *either*:

```
'paged' => 2
```

or

```
'offset' => 10
```

Comment: Ah, you're right! I thought the offset was applied on the initial posts, and then the loop began paginating the rest of the posts from there. A misunderstanding of the way WP_Query works I suppose. I don't know why I assumed simply using 'offset' would be semantically incorrect while technically correct. Anyways, thank you very much!